# Syntax highlighting using prism highlighter does not work with dynamic databiding

Tags: angularjs

I have issue with highlighting dynamic data fetched from database using $http service. When data is hardcoded between code element highlighting is working fine, but when a i tried to show dynamic  data using angular data binding  {{singlePractise.code}} it is not work at all. Example is shown bellow:

```
 myApp.directive('prism', [function() {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.ready(function() {
            Prism.highlightElement(element[0]);
        });
    }
   };
  }]
 );
```

HTML:

```
 <code class="language-javascript" prism>{{singlePractise.code}}</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in almost al the cases when you use 3rd party plugin with AngularJS. Content is not yet compiled when you want to apply the plugin.

the fastest solution would be to use **$timeout**:

```
myApp.directive('prism', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       $timeout(function(){
          Prism.highlightElement(element[0]);
       }, 0);      
    }
  };
}
```